# Is there a programming language with parameters in the function name

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

Often code is not as readable as it could be because parameters are always at the end of the function name. Ex.: `addDaysToDate(5, myDate)`.

I thought about a more readable syntax like this:

```
function add(days)DaysTo(date) {
  // Some implementation
}

var myDate = new Date()
add(5)DaysTo(myDate)
```

And you could go really crazy:

```
addA(5)('dollar')CouponTo(order)If(user)IsLoggedIn
```

So here is my question: Are there any languages that incorporate this concept?

Comment: Objective-C, and perhaps its successor Swift (not sure).

Comment: Smalltalk is one such language.

Comment: [Smalltalk messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk#Messages)

Comment: 'Not as readable as it could be' is merely opinion. The same notation has been working in mathematics for hundreds of years.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a generous interpretation of the phrase "is there", then: Algol 60 could look like your example. Specifically, it allowed a form of comment in procedure parameters.

```
 add(5) Days To: (myDate);
```

The specific rule in the grammar that permits this is:

```
<parameter delimiter> ::= , | ) <letter string> : (
```

which is to say, the parameters in a procedure statement can be separated by a comma (as is common) or by an arbitrary sequence of letters delimited by `)` and `:(`.

Spaces are everywhere ignored, so they're ok here too.

The letter-string is treated as a comment, so as for all comments, it has no bearing on what the code actually does. This is just as valid as the previous example:

```
add(5) Bananas To: (myDate);
```

It seems curious to me now, nearly 45 years after I last used this, that the comment part can only contain letters, no digits.

```
 <letter string> ::= <letter> | <letter string> <letter>
```

[Revised Report on the Algorithmic Language ALGOL 60](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/ALGOL/report/Algol60_revised_report_CACM.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Pogoscript https://github.com/featurist/pogoscript

> There are no keywords in PogoScript. All control structures use the same syntax rules as regular functions and methods, so it's very easy to write your own control structures
>
> Arguments and parameters can be placed anywhere in the name of a function or method call. The careful placement of an argument or a parameter can give it a lot of meaning.

```
sing (n) bottlesOfBeerOnTheWall =
    if (n > 0)
        console.log ((n) bottlesOfBeerOnTheWall)
        sing (n - 1) bottlesOfBeerOnTheWall

(n) bottlesOfBeerOnTheWall =
    "#((n) bottles) of beer on the wall, #((n) bottles) of beer.\n" +
    "Take one down, pass it around, #((n - 1) bottles) of beer on the wall."

(n) bottles =
    if (n == 0)
        "no bottles"
    else if (n == 1)
        "1 bottle"
    else
        "#(n) bottles"

sing 99 bottlesOfBeerOnTheWall
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift has it, and it's amazing. I wish every modern language had this feature, because:

`performAction(open, object, anotherObject, 42, 69, 360, 666, true, false)`

Can you guess what that does?

How about this?

`performAction(open, by: object, upon: anotherObject, afterSeconds: 42, cooldownDelay: 69, locationX: 360, y: 666, displayResults: true, repeat: false)`

If you think that's a contrived example, there are WAY more obtuse functions in an average game/app project's codebase.

With argument labels inside every function call, the code is readable at each point of use, even when sharing it as copy/pasted text on forums etc., where an IDE's autocomplete or documentation isn't available.